# Pusher chat kit tutorial not working as expected

Tags: ios, chat, chatbot, pusherswift

I want to create a simple chat app demo using pusher chat kit.
I am following the pusher provided [tutorial](https://docs.pusher.com/chatkit/quick_start/swift) .I am following documentation as it is but its not working in my case .
According to pusher documentation Chatmanger class object should be instantiated as follow:

`chatManager = ChatManager(
            instanceLocator: "YOUR INSTANCE LOCATOR",
            tokenProvider: PCTokenProvider(url: "YOUR TEST TOKEN ENDPOINT"),
            userId: "YOUR USER ID"
        )`

but in my case when i follow same code in my demo project there is an error appeared with following parameter correction Error .

[image]
I don't know Where i am doing wrong .

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is create an account in https://pusher.com/, and then create 
and  a chatkitt instance.

Now you have an account and chatkit instance. To acces The chatkit instance from your .js  using:

***const chatkit = new Chatkit.default({
    instanceLocator: "PUSHER_CHATKIT_INSTANCE_LOCATOR",
    key: "PUSHER_CHATKIT_KEY"
})***

***PUSHER_CHATKIT_INSTANCE_LOCATOR***: it's a string that you can see in pusher inside your account, it's a unique.
Additionally, you have the ***PUSHER_CHATKIT_KEY*** it's string and unique too.

both them (**PUSHER_CHATKIT_INSTANCE_LOCATOR**, and **key**), has to replace in the code above by the strings provided in your account.

i will leave you the tutorial about this step in this link:
https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-widget-javascript#create-your-chatkit-instance

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Diamantino  I'm working on the iOS chat application and I'm hoping to help iOS swift ,not in any other languages.